# android.database.sqlite.SQLiteException: near "mimetype"

Tags: android, exception, syntax-error, android-contacts

Hy everybody.

I have an error when I try to filter the names for the autocompleteTextView. I don't know what is wrong. The warning that appears is

**android.database.sqlite.SQLiteException: near "mimetype": syntax error: , while compiling: SELECT display_name, _id FROM view_data_restricted data WHERE (1) AND (data1 =? mimetype='vnd.android.cursor.item/group_membership' AND display_name like '%rui%') ORDER BY display_name**

Here is my code:

```
cursorContactosGrupos = getContentResolver().query(ContactsContract.Data.CONTENT_URI,
   new String[]{ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.GroupMembership.DISPLAY_NAME,    ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.GroupMembership._ID},
   ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.GroupMembership.GROUP_ROW_ID + " =? " + Data.MIMETYPE + "='" + ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.GroupMembership.CONTENT_ITEM_TYPE + "' AND " + ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.GroupMembership.DISPLAY_NAME + " like '%" + filter + "%'" ,
new String[]{String.valueOf(tempCurs.getLong(0))},
ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.GroupMembership.DISPLAY_NAME
);
```

Someone can help me ? thanks

Comment: Is there a reason you're not importing `ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds` instead of calling it several times?

Answer (score 0):

Looks like you need another `AND` in there before the MIME type argument.

Answer (score 0):

There is no `AND` before mimetype.